# How to trigger a machine call in user-mode applications for RISC-V platforms?

Tags: operating-system, riscv, hypervisor

I'm new to RISC-V and operating system developing, and I'm now trying to make a simple hypervisor-like interface in RISC-V. What stops me right now is that I have no idea about how to trigger a machine call (like RISC-SBI) which stands in firmware level and machine-mode for a user-mode applications? Since recently user-level applications communicate with kernel by system calls. However I may have to make the call skip the kernel and directly to the firmware. How to achieve this for a high-levl application?

I' really in a difficult time. So much thanks for your replies.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "skip the kernel" and "directly to the firmware". There's really just user vs. supervisor mode. Whether code is in the kernel or "firmware" is just a difference in where you're jumping (in supervisor mode all physical memory including firmware is accessible). You might find this tutorial helpful: https://osblog.stephenmarz.com/ch1.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here "skip" means that I want a jump from user mode to machine mode. I think I'm clear about the communication between user & supervisor mode. But how do I make a call to access machine mode? Since trap handler may treat my ecall as a call to s-mode?

Answer (score 0):

To make a system call, load register `a0` with which call you want to make (and possibly arguments to the syscall in other registers), then execute an `ecall` instruction with `01` in `func3`, which specifies Supervisor mode. To return to user mode after executing the system call code, the OS kernel executes an `sret` instruction, which returns to User mode from Supervisor mode. This is documented in the [Privileged Architecture specification](https://riscv.org/specifications/privileged-isa/), but I'll admit it requires a bit of knowledge ahead of time to figure out where to look.